# How to prompt an error when the user skips one of the edittext and enters data on the next edittext?

Tags: android

In this i have eight edittext,if the user enters the input at edittext1 skips edittext 2 and enters the data in edittext 3.I need to prompt an error to the user  and also the else part inside the try block doesnt gets executed.Where am i wrong how do i rectify this logical error

```
package com.sabari.results;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv10;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;
    EditText et5;
    EditText et6;
    EditText et7;
    EditText et8;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("CGPA Calculator");
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                et7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
                et8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);






                tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                int n=1;


                double no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8;
                double g1=0,g2=0,g3=0,g4=0,g5=0,g6=0,g7=0,g8=0;
                try {
                    no1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
                    if(no1>=5&&no1<=10)
                    {
                        g1=no1;
                        n=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                try{
                    no2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
                    if(no2>=5&&no2<=10)
                    {
                        g2=no2;
                        n=2;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
                    if(no3>=5&&no3<=10)
                    {
                        g3=no3;
                        n=3;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
                    if(no4>=5&&no4<=10)
                    {
                        g4=no4;
                        n=4;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no5 = Double.parseDouble(et5.getText().toString());
                    if(no5>=5&&no5<=10)
                    {
                        g5=no5;
                        n=5;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no6 = Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());
                    if(no6>=5&&no6<=10)
                    {
                        g6=no6;
                        n=6;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no7 = Double.parseDouble(et7.getText().toString());
                    if(no7>=5&&no7<=10)
                    {
                        g7=no7;
                        n=7;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }try {
                    no8 = Double.parseDouble(et8.getText().toString());
                    if(no8>=5&&no8<=10)
                    {
                        g8=no8;
                        n=8;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                double res = 0;



                if((g1<=10)&&(g2<=10)&&(g3<=10)&&(g4<=10)&&(g5<=10)&&(g6<=10)&&(g7<=10)&&(g8<=10)) {
                    res = (g1+g2+g3+g4+g5+g6+g7+g8) / n;
                    tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : " + res);
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Your CGPA is : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et2.setText("");
                et3.setText("");
                et4.setText("");
                et5.setText("");
                et6.setText("");
                et7.setText("");
                et8.setText("");
                tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : ");
                et1.setText("");

            }
        });


    }


}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 1st Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 2nd Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 3rd Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 4th Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:id="@+id/editText4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 5th Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:id="@+id/editText5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 6th Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 7th Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Enter Your 8th Semester GPA"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLength="4"

                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Calculate"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Clear"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your CGPA is :"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edited Class

```
package com.sabari.myapplication;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv10;
    EditText[] et=new EditText[8];
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("CGPA Calculator");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                et[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                et[2]=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                et[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                et[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                et[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                et[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
                et[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);


                tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

                 private void initAndValidateEditText(final EditText editText,final int index){
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        double res = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            double value=Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

                            if(value>=5&&value<=10){
                                if(index!=7){
                                    et[index+1].setEnabled(true);

                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[0], 0);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[1], 1);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[2], 2);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[3], 3);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[4], 4);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[5], 5);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[6], 6);
                                    initAndValidateEditText(et[7], 7);

                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if(index!=7){
                                    et[index+1].setEnabled(false);
                                }
                            }
                            res = value;
                            tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : " + res);


                        }

                    });
            }



            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : ");
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: You know this code is really inefficient? It is better to use a loop. As for your problem, you should check the previous EditText on focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `OnFocusChangeListener`. Let your activity implement one and override the interface method as:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {

    // if focus lost
    if (!arg1) {
        EditText et = (EditText) arg0;
        if (et.getText().toString().equals(""))
             et.setError("wtf...fill it!");
    } 

}
```

For each of your EditTexts, you have to do something like:

```
et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this); // this is your activity and it must implement View.OnFocusChangeListener interface
```

Comment: do i need to setup onfocuschange listener for each and every edit text .Please just show a complete code for checking one edit text box

Comment: @SabariGovindarajan firstly note that this code is designed such that when a user clicks (or reaches) any edittext and leave from it without filling data thats when the error appears. It will not show error for cases when a user directly starts entering text in editext 5 after edittext 1. Is this your use case?

Comment: yes that's my problem,i need to display an error message if the user enters data in 1st edit text and then skips to some other edit text instead of 2nd edit text

Comment: You can keep them disabled initially and then keep enabling them as the users keeps entering. That sound good?

Comment: yes that's what i need but i don't know to implement,as i'm new to android.Please show me a piece of code which solves my problem

Comment: I can try.  Post your layout XML

Comment: Thank you so much .I have added the xml

Comment: I figured out the logic. I was in a meeting...just started writing the code for the answer. Wait.

Answer (score 0):

The else doesn't get executed because your code doesn't get that far. Trying to parse a double from an empty string throws the exception and jumps into the catch block. What you really want to do is check that there's something in the `EditText` before you try to parse the double.

```
if(et1.getText().length() == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"All fields must be filled in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
else
{
    try
    {
        no1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
        if(no1>=5&&no1<=10)
        {
            g1=no1;
            n=1;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Failed to parse GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can achieve your target is to make your edittexts disabled by default and then you can enable them progressively as the user enters a valid value in each. Firstly, define your edittext XML as follows:

Begin be defining your edittexts like below so we can easily reference them:

```
// This variable will be a class variable so that any method can access it
EditText[] editTexts = new EditText[8];

// In your onCreate() init it
editTexts[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editTexts[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editTexts[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
editTexts[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
editTexts[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
editTexts[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
editTexts[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
editTexts[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
```

Now, we create a method in your class that does our validation along with enabling the next edittext for us:

```
private void initAndValidateEditText(final EditText editText, final int index) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

                if (value >= 5 && value <= 10) {
                    if (index != 7) {
                        editTexts[index + 1].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "wtf!...enter a valid GPA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (index != 7) {
                        editTexts[index + 1].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Within `onCreate()` only, pass each of your edittext to this method:

```
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[0], 0);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[1], 1);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[2], 2);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[3], 3);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[4], 4);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[5], 5);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[6], 6);
initAndValidateEditText(editTexts[7], 7);
```

Each of your edittexts are now validated (except the last one, take care of that by maybe enabling the submit button if index is 7 in the method above), so you don't need to do any other validation in your `onClick()`. Let me know if you run into any issues.

**[EDIT]**

Your entire class file will be as follows:

```
package com.sabari.myapplication;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv10;
    EditText[] et = new EditText[8];
    Button b1;
    Button b2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("CGPA Calculator");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        et[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        et[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        et[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        et[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        et[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        et[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);

        initAndValidateEditText(et[0], 0);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[1], 1);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[2], 2);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[3], 3);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[4], 4);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[5], 5);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[6], 6);
        initAndValidateEditText(et[7], 7);


        tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Calculate CGPA here by et[x].getText() methods

                tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : ");
            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });


    }


    private void initAndValidateEditText(final EditText editText, final int index) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                double value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

                if (value >= 5 && value <= 10) {
                    if (index != 7) {
                        et[index + 1].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (index != 7) {
                        et[index + 1].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }


}
```

Comment: @SabariGovindarajan You don't really have much experience in Java, right?

Comment: @SabariGovindarajan Check my edit above. You should really spend more time learning the basics to JAVA.

Comment: sorry for the late reply i solved the issue using if statements