# How to allow user to enter data in the edit text if only previous edittext are filled

Tags: android

I have eight `EditText`s in my code. I need to allow the user to enter the data in an `EditText` only if the previous `EditText` is filled, otherwise I have to prompt that one of the previous `EditText`s is blank. How do I achieve this?

```
package com.sabari.results;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv10;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;
    EditText et5;
    EditText et6;
    EditText et7;
    EditText et8;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("CGPA Calculator");
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                et7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
                et8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);






                tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                int n=1;


                double no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8;
                double g1=0,g2=0,g3=0,g4=0,g5=0,g6=0,g7=0,g8=0;

                try {
                    no1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
                    if(no1>=5&&no1<=10)
                    {
                        g1=no1;
                        n=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                try{
                    no2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
                    if(no2>=5&&no2<=10)
                    {
                        g2=no2;
                        n=2;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
                    if(no3>=5&&no3<=10)
                    {
                        g3=no3;
                        n=3;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
                    if(no4>=5&&no4<=10)
                    {
                        g4=no4;
                        n=4;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no5 = Double.parseDouble(et5.getText().toString());
                    if(no5>=5&&no5<=10)
                    {
                        g5=no5;
                        n=5;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no6 = Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());
                    if(no6>=5&&no6<=10)
                    {
                        g6=no6;
                        n=6;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no7 = Double.parseDouble(et7.getText().toString());
                    if(no7>=5&&no7<=10)
                    {
                        g7=no7;
                        n=7;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }try {
                    no8 = Double.parseDouble(et8.getText().toString());
                    if(no8>=5&&no8<=10)
                    {
                        g8=no8;
                        n=8;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }





                double res = 0;



                if(et1.getText().length()!=0||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0&&et4.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0&&et4.getText().length()!=0&&et5.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0&&et4.getText().length()!=0&&et5.getText().length()!=0&&et6.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0&&et4.getText().length()!=0&&et5.getText().length()!=0&&et6.getText().length()!=0&&et7.getText().length()!=0)||
                        (et1.getText().length()!=0&&et2.getText().length()!=0&&et3.getText().length()!=0&&et4.getText().length()!=0&&et5.getText().length()!=0&&et6.getText().length()!=0&&et7.getText().length()!=0&&et8.getText().length()!=0)) {


                    res = (g1+g2+g3+g4+g5+g6+g7+g8) / n;
                    tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : " + res);
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Your CGPA is : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter the required fields` ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et2.setText("");
                et3.setText("");
                et4.setText("");
                et5.setText("");
                et6.setText("");
                et7.setText("");
                et8.setText("");
                tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : ");
                et1.setText("");

            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: Don't re-ask questions. Edit your previous question with more information. I see you have not even responded to answers on your yesterday's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880715/how-to-prompt-an-error-when-the-user-skips-one-of-the-edittext-and-enters-data-o

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `return` to stop a code from running. so first check if the `EditText` is empty, then you will show your message and stop the code from running.
example

```
 if(mEditText.getText().toString().equals(""){
Toast.makeText(mContext,"Fill Text Boxes Accordingly",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
//stop the code from running
return; 
}
```